# Updating parts of a record in Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to update only parts of a database record? I have a table that lists a bunch of different items followed by their cost, but I would like to remove the cost from the item. For example:

Current table looks like this

```
---Item-------------
  Apple- 1.35
  Orange - 1.24
  Grape - 2.00
  ETC..
---------------------
```

I would like to update the table with the same records, but without the hyphened price at the end. There are hundreds of different records in this table, so I can't just update by a specific record. I've tried using wildcards, but I wasn't able to get the results I'm looking for. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would go for Mid:

```
SELECT t.ExistingField, 
  Trim(Mid([existingfield],1,InStr([existingfield],"-")-1)) AS NewData
FROM Table t
```

So:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Table.UpdatedField = Trim(Mid([existingfield],1,InStr([existingfield],"-")-1))
WHERE Table.ExistingField Like "*-*"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the part you want to remove always begins with a hyphen, and there won't be any hyphens as part of the item name then this code should do what you want:

```
update YourTable set item = left(item, instr(item,"-")-1)
```

Before you run the update you might want to try it as a select:

```
select left(item, instr(item,"-")-1) as newitem from YourTable
```

If your item name can contain hyphens maybe searching for a hyphen followed by a space would work: `"- "`

Also, a where clause should probably be used to avoid trying to update rows without the price part.

```
SELECT Left(item,InStr(item,"- ")-1) AS newitem
FROM YourTable
WHERE InStr(item,"- ") > 0;
```

Comment: How would this work for something with a hyphen in it's name?  i.e. some-item - 2.50

Comment: @user2366842 I'm afraid it wouldn't. It just removes everything after the first hyphen. I guess it should be possible to test for a pattern like `hyphen space number` though.

Comment: Cool...just trying to think of any possible pitfalls of what appears on the surface to be a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Get the [ParseWord](http://allenbrowne.com/func-10.html) function, stick it in a module, and reference it in your UPDATE query like so:

```
ParseWord([NameOfYourField], 1)
```

You can also use the [`Split()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-Function-876f246a-5144-44fa-889f-10078c7878f5?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US) to do the same thing.